# ActionView::Template::Error (THING can't be coerced into Fixnum):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Can anyone explain this error? Trying to divide and subtract in an ERB file. I am sure best practice is to do it in the controller, but would rather not.

```
            ActionView::Template::Error (AcctLedger can't be coerced into Fixnum): 
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      107:  
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      108:         <% if "myapp XL" == call.requested_type %> 
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      109:           <% if call.has_fee? %> 
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      110:             <% price = (price - call.has_fee)/2 %> 
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      111:           <% else %> 
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      112:             <% price = price/2 %> 
        Mar 09 00:25:34 myapp app/web.2:      113:           <% end %>
```

Comment: whats the value of `call.has_fee`? seems like its a boolean

Comment: did you try converting it to integer befor making the calculation, .to_i method from ruby. This is very basic, but It's the only idea I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `price` or `call.has_fee` returning an `AcctLedger` object, by any chance? This error is saying that `AcctLedger` has no idea how to act like a number, but you're trying to use it in a calculation.

You can see a similar thing if you try to add a number and a string:

```
1 + '1'
# TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
```